# Ошибка при обращении к элементам массива готовой модели

Tags: python, массивы, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Изучаю машинное обучение. Построил и обучил модель. сохранил ее в формате файла model.h5. Цитирую из примера по которому выполняю все операции:

> Давайте теперь перезагрузим это: 
>   `model1 = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path) 
>   model1.summary()`

Загружаю модель в своем коде:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

save_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'saved_models')
model_name = 'keras_cifar10_trained_model.h5'
model_path = os.path.join(save_dir, model_name)
number_of_images = 5


model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)
model.summary()
```

Далее в примере:

> Наконец, давайте посмотрим, как наша модель живет на нашем тестовом
>   наборе. Нам нужно перезагрузить данные, потому что они были искажены:
>
> `(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()`
>   `show_images(x_test[:num_images*num_images]) 
>   x_test =`
>   `x_test.astype('float32')/255`

И вот на этом моменте не понимаю, что делать. 
Пробовал так:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
show_images(x_test[:0])
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')/255
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "F:/Work/Projects/Image_classification/cifar_model_test.py", line 30, in 
>       show_images(x_test[:0])
>     File "F:/Work/Projects/Image_classification/cifar_model_test.py", line 23, in show_images
>       plt.imshow(Image.fromarray(images[image_index]))
>   IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Явно, не правильно обращаюсь к элементам массива, но не пойму как это сделать правильно.

Попробовал обратиться просто к первому элементу
`(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
show_images(x_test[0])
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')/255`

Вывело искаженные изображения, как и было сказано в примере, что они искажены. 
Но тогда не понятно, что имелось под этой конструкцией: **show_images(x_test[:num_images*num_images])**

функция show_images:

```
def show_images(images):
    plt.figure(1)
    image_index = 0
    for i in range(0,number_of_images):
        for j in range(0,number_of_images):
            plt.subplot2grid((number_of_images, number_of_images),(i,j))
            plt.imshow(Image.fromarray(images[image_index]))
            image_index +=1
            plt.gca().axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
            plt.gca().axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: можете добавить в вопрос определение функции `show_images()`?

Comment: добавил функцию. заранее могу сказать, что в целом опыт с этим примером увенчался успехом, но вот что имел в виду автор под такими аргументами функции, я так и не понял